# How to get attributes of Polygon by providing X and Y values of Clicking position in Postgis?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I am looking for query help. I want to give lat and long values to query and get in result all values of that polygon.

```
> Geometry is polygon layer (Grids of 10x10 m)
> 
> Select * from Geometry_table where ST_x= 32 and ST_Y = 72 ;
```

Comment: could elaborate a bit on your use case? Perhaps there is a better solution to that. In case it has to be that way, try this: `Select * from Geometry_table where ST_X(geom_column)= 32 and ST_Y(geom_column)= 72 ;`

Comment: I have geom table in which i have grid of polygons. Table is looking like GID,Geom,attribute1, attribute2. I want to pass x and y value to query , these values are coming from click by client on map view.

Comment: ah, so you want to retrieve the polygons that overlap with a given x,y pair.. right?

Comment: Jim  Select * from Geometry_table where ST_X(geom_column)= 32 and ST_Y(geom_column)= 72 ;           ERROR:  Argument to ST_X() must be a point
SQL state: XX000 because we are using polygon

Comment: You are right jim. I want to provide x and y, and get that polygon valuue.

Comment: It will be look like: Select * from table_name a
where ST_intersects(a.geom,XY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need `ST_MakePoint` to create a point based on x,y coordinates, and then `ST_Contains` to check if the given coordinates lie inside of any polygon (grid cell):

```
SELECT * 
FROM geometry_table
WHERE ST_Contains(geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(32,72),4326))
```

- This query assumes your grid has the SRID `4326` (WGS84). Change it to the right SRS in case it differs from your table.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c81db44f2ffa4fcc616161798cbd733)

Comment: After transform : SELECT col1,col2
FROM tablename a
WHERE ST_intersects(ST_transform(a.geom,4326),ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long,lat),4326));

Comment: @UmairAsghar nice it helped. Intersects also work, but since we're dealing with points and grid cells `st_contains` is also an alternative. You can play with both and see which one best fits your query. cheers and happy coding :)